# Inject javascript body in blazor wasm dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

All the methods I have seen in blazor wasm to inject Javascript involves calling a javascript function. what if I want to inject a dynamic javascript function block.
Example: `await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("<script>alert('A')</script",null);`
Is this possible? "InvokeAsync" only seems to accept a function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this call the  function name and then pass the data as an argument, as you're directly invoking JS, the script tag is unnecessary

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Hello!");
```

Comment: Although, this works, I need to pass a dynamic custom function. see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function in index.html

```
 <script>
        window.addCode = (code) => {
            var JS = document.createElement('script');
            JS.text = code;
            document.body.appendChild(JS);
        };        
    </script>
```

call it from razor page: `await JS.InvokeAsync<object>("addCode","alert('A')")`

Comment: yup that works just be aware of dom xss https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: I'm not sure why you would prefer this at all compared to the other one. You might as well just `eval` if you want to do that, and remember: there's always a way around eval. Why not just use the other solution?